# Return lists that have the highest value per group

Tags: python

I currently have a list of locations that I would like to sort out.

The list looks like the following:

```
list = [['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 4],['Location 2', 6],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5]]
```

The goal is to select the highest value of each list in index 1 for every location. The final results should look like the following:

```
correctList = [['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 6],['Location 3', 5]]
```

Locations with the same integer value has no preference.

The solution that I have now is appending each location to there own list based on name. Then from each list using a `max()` operation on each location list.

Comment: Is your solution not working?

Comment: Please share your attempt, so that we can give you informed advice. That said, this seems like a standard use case of dictionaries. Have you tried using them here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to select the list with the `max` second element, once the lists have been sorted using the first element:

```
s = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
[max(k) for i,k in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x[0])]
[['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 6], ['Location 3', 5]]
```

Where:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])

[['Location 1', 5],
 ['Location 1', 4],
 ['Location 1', 5],
 ['Location 2', 5],
 ['Location 2', 6],
 ['Location 2', 5],
 ['Location 3', 5],
 ['Location 3', 5]]
```

Note that `max` will give the desired output when fed a set of lists as:

```
max(['Location 1', 5], ['Location 1', 4], ['Location 1', 5])
#['Location 1', 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for an O(*n*) solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 4],
     ['Location 2', 6],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5]]

dd = defaultdict(int)

for location, value in L:
    dd[location] = max(dd[location], value)

print(dd)
# defaultdict(int, {'Location 1': 5, 'Location 2': 6, 'Location 3': 5})
```

This gives a dictionary mapping. If you are keen on a list of lists:

```
res = list(map(list, dd.items()))

print(res)
# [['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 6], ['Location 3', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to compute the maximum value per location in *O(n)*:

```
data = [['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 5], ['Location 3', 5], ['Location 1', 4], ['Location 2', 6],
        ['Location 3', 5], ['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 5]]

groups = {}
for location, value in data:
    if location not in groups:
        groups[location] = value
    else:
        groups[location] = max(groups[location], value)

result = [[location, value] for location, value in groups.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 6], ['Location 3', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this, it is very easy to group by one key and calculate something for each group:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 4],['Location 2', 6],['Location 3', 5],['Location 1', 5],['Location 2', 5]],
                  columns=["location", "value"])
df.groupby("location").max()
#             value
# location         
# Location 1      5
# Location 2      6
# Location 3      5
```

If you absolutely need a list of lists afterwards, that is also possible:

```
df.groupby("location").max().reset_index().values.tolist()
# [['Location 1', 5], ['Location 2', 6], ['Location 3', 5]]
```

---

Note that if this is the only thing you want to do with this data, this is probably overkill. But if you need to do some more analysis with it, getting used to `pandas` can speed up a lot of things, since most of its methods are vectorized and written in C.

Comment: This seems like overkill for the problem. Why use an external library when a dictionary would suffice?

Comment: @JordanSinger: Because they might want to do more involved stuff with it afterwards.

Comment: But that's not what the question was asking for, and only adds overhead to the code.

Comment: @JordanSinger: True. However it does solve the question. For large lists it will even be faster as soon as you do something else with it (since consuming the list into the dataframe is probably the bottleneck and `pandas` is mostly implemented in C)

Comment: @JordanSinger: Anyways, added a disclaimer to the answer that this might be overkill.